# How can I paste a specific string into my text by a shortcut key?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, text-processing

I want to use keyboard combination Alt-E to write my email address, rather than have to type it out all the time.

I know how to create a custom key in

```
unity-control-center
```

- Keyboard
- Shortcuts
- Custom Shortcuts

...but I can't figure out what to write in the **Command:** field. I've tried:

```
echo "my@emailaddress.com"
```

and

```
cat "my@emailaddress.com"
```

and

```
sed "my@emailaddress.com"
```

... but as you can tell, I don't know what I'm doing. I've just been trying things from a websearch "linux custom key output specified text".

It doesn't seem as if a macro would be necessary, nor the installation of another application. I've found a couple of other solutions here that both involve installing another application (`autokey`, `xdotool`). It seems to me that there would be a command on Linux that I would be able to use in the **Command:** field. Could that be true?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can run a command almost essentially in a terminal and have it auto-type to any application window that happens to be open & selected.

Autokey does, and works great and is very simple to just type some keys, essentially just use

```
keyboard.send_keys("my@emailaddress.com")
```

and set a hotkey and you're done.

Comment: Thanks. In the **Keyboard** settings, I wonder what the **Command:** field actually means and admits.

As I mentioned, I'm trying to avoid installing the application if I can avoid it.

Comment: In XFCE the keyboard shortcuts seem to just run a command, just like running it in a terminal, good for starting a program but not so good for desktop integrated typing. I suspect unity's similar

Comment: I like the sound of this, but the command `keyboard.send_keys("my@emailaddress.com")` doesn't include any mention of `autokey`.

To clarify: Would the command `keyboard.send_keys("my@emailaddress.com")` go into the
> System Settings...
> Keyboard
> Shortcuts
> Custom Shortcuts
> Command: field?

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplest solution

*"It seems to me that there would be a command on Linux that I would be able to use in the Command: field. Could that be true?"* No, not without installing *anything* additionally, but

..Make xdotool type it for you. 
You have several options and tools, but the easiest / simplest solution is to add the following command to a shortcut:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 0.2 && xdotool type 'monkey@zoo.com'"
```

The `sleep 0.2` is to prevent your actual keypress (shortcut) to interfere with the virtual keypress by xdotool.

#### Note

Depending on what else you have installed, you might need to install `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Comment: This no longer works in Linux Mint 21.1. When you click the shortkey it just randomly opens and closes a bunch of windows and menus. Bizarre.